# python pyodbc bulk select with where tuples

Tags: select, pyodbc, bulk

Hello I am looking for a “bulk” select by pyodbc

```
Select col1, col2 from table 1 where col1=df[col] and col2=df[col2]
```

or

```
select col1, col2 from table1 where col1, col2=” df_tupes
```

df_tupes would be [(col1val1, col2val1), (col1val2, col2val2)]

Not necessarily for two columns but multiple columns

Comment: You might try using  `to_sql` to push the DataFrame to a temporary table, then `SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN temp_table tt ON t1.col1 = tt.col1 AND t1.col2 = tt.col2`

Comment: Yes that would be a workaround. cursor.execute inserts tho allow for bulk inserts of tuples. trying to figure out a similar solution for selects.